How do we dispatch many multiprocessing jobs robustly in Python without memory errors?
I'm working on a Python project where I need to run a large grid search optimization using multiprocessing. My challenge is to dispatch a large number of jobs without running into memory issues.
Here's my current approach:

Memory Check Function: Checks if the current memory usage is within a specified limit.
Optimization Task Function: Runs the optimization using SciPy's minimize on given parameters.
Main Function:


Creates a pool of worker processes.
Dispatches subsets of tasks (G') to the pool.
Waits for the current tasks to complete.
Checks memory usage before dispatching the next subset.
Updates the best result and parameters if the current batch yields a better result.
Closes the pool after all tasks are processed.
Here's my code:

import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from typing import List, Dict, Any
import time

# Function to check current memory usage
def memory_usage_within_limit(limit: float) -> bool:
    """Check if the current memory usage is within the specified limit."""
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    return memory_info.available / memory_info.total >= limit

# Function to run the optimization task
def optimization_task(params: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """Run optimization using SciPy minimize on the given parameters."""
    def objective_function(x):
        return np.sum(x**2)  # Example: simple quadratic function
    result = minimize(objective_function, np.array(list(params.values())))
    return {'params': params, 'result': result}

# Function to run the optimization in parallel while managing memory usage
def run_optimization(grid: List[Dict[str, Any]], memory_limit: float, num_workers: int):
    """Run the optimization tasks in parallel, managing memory usage."""
    best_result = None
    best_params = None
    pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)  # Create a pool of workers

    try:
        for subset in grid:
            # Wait until memory usage is within limit
            while not memory_usage_within_limit(memory_limit):
                time.sleep(1)  # Wait until memory usage is within limit

            # Dispatch the subset of tasks to the worker pool using .map
            async_results = pool.map(optimization_task, subset)

            # Update the best result and params if the current results are better
            for result in async_results:
                if best_result is None or result['result'].fun < best_result['result'].fun:
                    best_result = result
                    best_params = result['params']
    finally:
        pool.close()  # Close the pool
        pool.join()  # Wait for all worker processes to finish
        pool.terminate()  # Ensure all processes are terminated
    return best_result, best_params

# Define hyperparameter grid
hyperparameter_grid = [
    {'x1': i, 'x2': j} for i in range(-2, 3) for j in range(-2, 3)  # Reduced grid for small example
]

# Split grid into subsets
subset_size = 3
grid_subsets = [hyperparameter_grid[i:i + subset_size] for i in range(0, len(hyperparameter_grid), subset_size)]

# Run the optimization with memory management
memory_limit = 0.1  # Allow usage up to 90% of memory
num_workers = 1  # Example with 1 worker

start_time = time.time()
best_result, best_params = run_optimization(grid_subsets, memory_limit, num_workers)
end_time = time.time()

duration = end_time - start_time
print("Best Result:", best_result)
print("Best Params:", best_params)
print("Duration:", duration)

I appreciate any help or suggestions on how to improve the robustness of my multiprocessing job dispatching to avoid memory errors -- especially because this can't be a new problem. I bet it's been solved before. Thank you!

While this approach might works, I wish I could continually dispatch multiprocessing jobs without having memory issues. Ideally, I would like to continually dispatch jobs, and after they run for a bit and the memory increase stops, dispatch more jobs while always keeping a safe margin from the total memory limit. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement it?
First attempt, but I feel these are amateur attempts to my issues:
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import time

def example_task(arg):
    time.sleep(5)  # Simulate a task that takes time
    return f"Processed {arg}"

def memory_safe_worker(func, args, memory_limit, sleep_interval=1):
    """
    Wrapper function to monitor memory usage and manage jobs accordingly.
    """
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    jobs = []
    
    def check_memory():
        mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
        return mem.available / mem.total
    
    try:
        while args:
            current_memory = check_memory()
            if current_memory > memory_limit:
                arg = args.pop(0)
                job = pool.apply_async(func, (arg,))
                jobs.append(job)
                print(f"Dispatched a job for argument {arg}. Available memory: {current_memory * 100:.2f}%")
            else:
                print(f"Waiting for memory to free up. Available memory: {current_memory * 100:.2f}%")
            time.sleep(sleep_interval)
            # Clean up completed jobs
            jobs = [job for job in jobs if not job.ready()]
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminating all jobs...")
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    memory_limit = 0.2  # Adjust this to set how much memory should be available before dispatching new jobs (e.g., 0.2 means 20% of total memory should be free)
    args = [i for i in range(10)]  # Example arguments for tasks

    memory_safe_worker(example_task, args, memory_limit)


i have had many trials at this, all trials failed because the users can always create a situation that triggers an out of memory error, you just have to make a good initial estimation then handle the error when it happens, there will always be a user that presses "run" then directly opens 100 tabs of chrome, just give users control over how many threads they want to use then hold them responsible for providing the memory.

What are you trying to do? Run the largest number of possible jobs simultaneously or maximise overall throughput. The two options are almost never the same. There is a sweet spot where cores are working at a level that just about saturates memory bandwidth. After that you just run the CPU hotter and get the answer more slowly.
